# React Server Side Rendering - addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a server side rendering react app (because I need Facebook Seo as well).

A part of my app requires to get window.innerWidth.

I have been searching for a long time, most of them says you cannot find window on server side, so you need to do **rendering on client side as well**.

I'm not sure how things work, I have componentdidmount but my windowWidth is forever 0.

After server rendering, our bundle.js will kick in and window on client side will work right? How come it's still 0?

```
state = {
      windowWidth: 0
}
    handleResize(){
        this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth});
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
     }

    componentWillUnmount () {
     window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);

    }

render() {
return (<div>{this.state.windowWidth}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you attaching a function to set the new width to a "resize" listener which means only when you resize the screen the new width will added to state. You need to set the width inside `componentDidMount` and then you will have it width right on mount.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnowzqxzlw)

CODE:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      windowWidth: 0
    };
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.windowWidth && <p>{this.state.windowWidth}</p>}</div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: tried this already, doesn't work, this.state.windowWidth is still 0 because it's server side rendering? i don't know how else to troubleshoot

Comment: well, it cant be the case because `componentDidMount ` is only exist on the client. Means , it only get called on the client. It should work try to copy past the code in a test route.

Comment: if i run a non-ssr code it works, but if i try to run the code with nodejs and ssr, it doesn't work. I assume ComponentDidMount is client side too, so I event try to use it on child->child->child->child->component it also doesn't update the windowwidth.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial then you have another problem. I dont know how you trying to render React on SSR but you really should use proper framework for that. I use this method all the time and it works. check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/5z51ll9l6n it created with Next.js container and use SSR for full demonstration (and it works) . BTW , you really should use Next to SSR React.. its the best.

Comment: thank u. i just use rendertostring on server side, and hydrate on client side... nextjs seems like some big learning curve, i will take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-bootstrap-webpack-ssr-starter/blob/master/src/server/SSR/src/server.js I copied this server side code. Everything else including cssmodule and redux works, but i don't know why i cannot get window resize working.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial let me tell you that, I've been exactly in your spot not a while ago.Tried to hack around React to use SSR just not to learn Next.js.. listen , its as easy as it get and it will make your life SO MUCH easier! all these workarounds are awful dev experience. Their "get started" section is gold. Just saying (:

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial the example you shared not going to work for you. This is still server rendered therefor - no react lifecycles exist. You simply can't use any react feature that way.

Comment: this is not server side rendered?? what's the diff?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I dont want to mislead you BUT Im 99% sure your can't use React lifecycles in that way you trying with this code sample. because Its basically sent plain html to the client and missing the whole React thing that way. imo these workarounds so awful that they are more effort then benefit...

Comment: Hello thanks for recommending nextjs, with your code event listener will work. However, at launch it will still be 0 because it's server rendered. So i need to add this.state.windowWidth === 0 && this.handleResize inside render().